# About the onto functions

Tags: functions

If the range of a function belongs to all real numbers . Is the function necessarily onto?
My answer: No, we cannot say so until we know the co domain.

Comment: Yes, we can not say anything about surjection, if we codomain is not mentioned.

Comment: Your conclusion is correct, but if you are answering no on this style of question it is always good to provide an explicit counterexample. Can you think of one?

Comment: That is true i think now cause i could not find any counterexample. But can you please help me with the proof?

Comment: By "If the range of a function belongs to all real numbers" do you mean that it includes all real numbers or that all of the range is real numbers.  As written $f(x)=1$ qualifies because its range belongs to the real numbers.

Comment: The range of the function $\ f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\ $ defined by $\ f\left(x\right)=x $ is the entire set of real numbers, but it's not onto because its range is a proper subset of its codomain, the set of complex numbers.

Answer (score -1):

If the function is onto and the range of the function is every real number then we can conclude that domain of it is R. This is only valid if f : R -> R. Else in all other cases we can't guess the function domain.